# Can you make an Ubuntu bootable USB with a 4GB flash drive?

Tags: usb, live-usb

How big is the Ubuntu download when all is said and done? I want to make a bootable USB using a 4 gig flash drive. Would that be large enough or do I need to find a larger flash drive? If a larger one is needed, how big would you recommend at minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse. Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS ISO is around 1 GB. You can check it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64). You are good to go.
I have used Universal USB Installer as mentioned [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) on three of my systems to install that version.

Here is the size of this .iso from my Ubuntu desktop:

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu/Downloads# ls -l ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ashu ashu 1054867456 Feb 17 21:01 ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

It's 1054867456(around 1006 MB)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, for me it only ends up being 1.3GB-1.4GB. A 4GB flashdrive should be fine, so long as you tell it to discard changes on shutdown as opposed to preserving it in a persistent partition.